# Android Studio Folders and Libraries

Tags: android

Hi I am writing a project on Android studio. First I have my project in C disk then I copied it on the D disk. I opened both projects. The one on the D disk can not find its libraries now. Here is the screenshot of C:

[image: C]

And this is the project structure of D:
[image]

what should I do to find the libraries of the project in disk D.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try pressing Alt+Enter in the warnings to get the hints.

Comment: I think the problem is with the project files structure. The libraries ı want to use are same but the paths should be different. There a more files in the project which is in D disk.